# Build WebRTC on Linux using host libc++

Tags: c++, linux, c++17, webrtc, libc++

When attempting to build WebRTC on Linux it has a ton of undefined symbols in both the static and even the shared build. These include basic_string things in the std::__Cr namespace (I guess that is Googles custom libc++?), SSL functions, protobuf stuff, and things like dbus, free among other things.

Configuring it with `use_custom_libcxx=false` in the gn args it will simply fail to compile due to some emplace function missing in optional.

The host system has an up to date libc++ and clang toolchain installed and available, which is fully aware of said function, however I have not found a way to make the webRTC build aware of it and use that instead.

Preferably I want a static build of libwebrtc, that uses the host libc++ and is compatible with the rest of the code (which uses the host libc++) that will ultimately link libwebrtc.

Comment: This appears to be a change post m119 bc that was building for me. Now that I am trying to migrate to m122, I am also have the same issue. I made a post in the webrtc group here about it: https://groups.google.com/g/discuss-webrtc/c/DWhhJLcWJf8

Comment: I love how their response is "Yeah well you changed build flags". So in other words, everyone better build that exact same configuration using the exact same things, otherwise it will fail because it is an extremely fragile piece of code that won't compile without all the compiler oddities and stuff they count on. GG google.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding building webrtc with `use_custom_libcxx=false`, I was running into the same issue as you (`no matching member function for call to 'emplace'`). The problem was actually reported to LLVM in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/61705) and there's also a workaround mentioned in there.

To fix it, simply declare a default constructor and default it outside of the class. In my case, I only had to do that for `webrtc::LossBasedBweV2::Config` (in `modules/congestion_controller/goog_cc/loss_based_bwe_v2.<h/cc>`.

After that, I was able to build webrtc with libstdc++. Worked with both the sysroot provided by webrtc and the host system.